# Nelmioapibundme - How to delete the json format in the body request

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

I just want to make a post to be able to test the creation of a user in my application but every time I have an error because of a parameter in addition sent in the body request

[You can see format json in the body request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOn9A.png)

Please how to remove the "_format":"json" in the body request.

This is my config.yml with FosRest and Nelmio Api Bundle

[See my config.yml with fosrest and nelmio api bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ryNH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still looking for a solution but, just in case someone end here looking for a solutoin,  I ran into the exact same issue and according to the [documentation FAQ](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/faq.html), you need to add this to your `config.yml:`

```
nelmio_api_doc:
# remove "_format" param from sandbox request
sandbox:
      request_format:
          method: accept_header
```